# Is there SQL-syntax aware Swing component?

Tags: java, swing, syntax-highlighting

I am looking for some Java Swing component (textarea like) which is aware of SQL syntax - meaning it recognizes and highlights it.

If there isn't I will need to do it myself, any useful advices there how not waste too much of time (eg. which component to use) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[JSyntaxPane](http://code.google.com/p/jsyntaxpane/) appears to support SQL highlighting (I have not tried it myself).

Comment: Looks good, I will test it out in following days and will report here. Thank you so far.

Comment: Ok I am satisfied :D Works really nice.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [Ostermiller's Syntax Highlighter](http://ostermiller.org/syntax/) before. It is as simple as:

```
HighlightedDocument document = new HighlightedDocument();
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane(document);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [SQuirreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/). After a quick look at the source code I think it uses Swing and it has an SQL editor with syntax highlight and even content assist.

Answer (score 1):

The MIT-licensed [jEdit syntax package](http://syntax.jedit.org/) supports SQL and many other languages.

I've use the commercial [JIDE Code Editor](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/editor.htm), which uses jEdit and works very well.

Comment: If only JIDE Code Editor would some day come out of the beta stage... I think it has been beta maybe for two years now.

Comment: @Carlos: did you find any major problems? I just started to use it and find it ok so far. When did gmail come out of beta?

Comment: No. I'm sure it works and most certainly better than jEdit syntax package. But obviously there is still something missing, otherwise they wouldn't keep it in beta. I was just wondering if they are actively developing it. I didn't mean to criticize the component itself.

Comment: @Carlos: hey now I remember you from the [JIDE answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055647/looking-for-a-feedback-on-jide/2058811#2058811 "JIDE Fan Club")! No wonder... Why don't you just ask them on the forum, then. You know David will get back to you in no time.

Comment: It's not an issue for me at the moment, that's just something I've been wondering. At some point I need to replace the syntax package, but that's not the most urgent problem. I want to clarify, that my original comment was not meant as criticism or to discourage from using it, just an observation.